# MyBatis update timeout no ejecuta

Tags: java, sql-server, mybatis

Cuando ejecuto un UPDATE en MyBatis se queda colgado, si pongo timeout"20" interrumpe la ejecución por el exceso de tiempo.

Mapper:

```
<update id="actualizarUnaSalida" timeout="20">
    UPDATE dbo.TbSALIDAS 
    SET Facturado=1
    WHERE IdSalidas = 599
</update>
```

Llamada a Update

```
session = ConnectionFactory.getSessionCatalogos().openSession();
daoDetalleCatalogo = session.getMapper(DetalleCatalogoEspecialBeanMapper.class);

daoDetalleCatalogo.actualizarUnaSalida();//<- Entra pero no sale
```

Como podéis ver el UPDATE es los más sencillo posible por si el error venía por parámetros o algo así.

Aunque no ponga los Mapeos eso está bien ya que uso la clase DetalleCatalogoEspecialBeanMapper para hacer SELECT y eso si funciona.

Como detalle quiero comentar que cuando ejecuto la aplicación y se queda colgado en el Update si abro el SQL Management e intento hacer un UPDATE tampoco me funciona, es como que lo deja bloqueado, en cambio SELECT si ejecuta.

Si alguien puede darme alguna pista lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido detectar el error.

Lo que estaba pasando era que se bloqueaba los Update, Delete e Insert por no haber cerrado sesión en la consulta anterior.

Gracias a esta consulta de [aqui](https://horacioag.wordpress.com/2015/01/20/script-para-el-diagnostico-de-bloqueos-en-sql-server/) he conseguido saber que consulta estaba bloqueando mi Update y así encontrar el error de bloqueo de la base de datos Sql server.